# Getting location.hostname from new created window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having problem with getting location.hostname for newly created window in javascript.
For example I have following situation:

> var win_handler = window.open('/window parametars/');

I would like to grab hostname from this new window and compare it with main window hostname, for example something like this:

> if (win_handler.location.hostname == window.location.hostname) { //do
>   something}

And this works perfect on safari, opera, firefox, chrome ...
But with ie im having problem, it says "Permission denied"?

Does anyone know how to solve this to work on ie also?

Comment: You'll have to pay an additional license fee to MicroSoft to gain permission in Internet Exploding to use the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've violating the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

> The same origin policy permits scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with
>   no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and
>   properties across pages on different sites.